# Is there any way to get all ookla server list and store this into a data base?

Tags: mysql, database, list, server, speed-test

i wanted to insert all available ookla servers into my data base for the speed test purpose for my android application. But i am not getting any way to find out how to get this servers list and insert into my database table of mysqldb.
How can i get this list and how to bulk insert into my db?

Comment: Get list from https://c.speedtest.net/speedtest-servers-static.php and parse it into your DB using LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: it just gives the list near my location. I need to store all the servers (world wide).This link only works in this geo location.